# Cannot install logpy package on python 3.6.9

Tags: python, pip, python-3.6

I have been trying to install logpy by running

```
pip3 install 'http://github.com/MHordecki/LogPy'
```

But all I have been getting is:

> Cannot unpack file /tmp/pip-duusgw97-unpack/LogPy (downloaded from /tmp/pip-meb6tcd7-build, content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8); cannot detect archive format
>   Cannot determine archive format of /tmp/pip-meb6tcd7-build

I have also tried:

```
pip3 install logpy
```

And I have been getting;

> Collecting logpy
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b7/58/53ce8f101c036dd848f86fe6ebedcd849aa4802e1cfc5f613a31f7e93852/LogPy-1.0.tar.gz
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>         File "/tmp/pip-build-_jzw89c0/logpy/setup.py", line 6, in 
>           long_description = open('README.rst').read(),
>       FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.rst'
>
> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-_jzw89c0/logpy/

Answer (score 0):

[LogPy](https://pypi.org/project/LogPy/1.0.1/) last released: Nov 19, 2012. Doesn't have downloadable packages or stource code at PyPI. Are you sure you still want to install it?

Well, to install from Github you need `git`. The command is

```
pip3 install 'git+https://github.com/MHordecki/LogPy.git'
```

Comment: After running the given command. I am getting this error::--

Error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'git': 'git' while executing command git clone -q https://github.com/MHordecki/LogPy.git /tmp/pip-tl_hrzkw-build
Cannot find command 'git'

Comment: You need `git` to install from Github. You can also download a ZIP archive from GIthub, unzip it and run `python setup.py install`

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't realized that. Thanks very much. It worked after installing git